# How to sort Unique JSON Object form JSON array in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am a beginner in Ionic 2. I have successfully fetch data from URL into an array.In my json response, there are multiple duplicate **JSON Object**. I required to sort this json object and need to display in **accordion-list**

**This is my json response:**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Thane"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Thane"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Thane"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Thane"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Parasailing",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Kayaking",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Rubber Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride ",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Kayaking",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride ",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Motar Lounch",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Yacht",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Rubber Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Rubber Boat",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Raigad"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat ",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "ATV Ride",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "WaterScooter",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Jet ski",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "WaterScooter",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Parasailing",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "WaterScooter",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Kayaking",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Banana ride ",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        },
        {
            "ws_type": "Parasailing",
            "ws_district": "Sindhudurg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is my code**

I am sorting json object with this following code but i am not getting required result:

```
var  result = _.values((this.information.reduce((r,o) => {
            r[o.ws_type] = r[o.ws_type] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_type: o.ws_type, children: []};
            //r[o.ws_district] = r[o.ws_district] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_district: o.ws_district, children: []};
            r[o.ws_type].children.push( r[o.ws_district] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_district: o.ws_district});
            return r;
          },{})));
```

**This is i am getting as output**
[image]

**Required Output**

I want that Raigad district only one time in my list.This is coming because of multiple duplicate json object in my **result JSON Array**

**Required Result:**

**- Speed Boat**

- Raigad
- Ratnagiri
- Sindhudurg
- Thane

Thanks.Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the reduce method for filtering it out

```
 let result = results.reduce((cur,prev)=>{
      const type = prev['ws_type'].replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '')
      if(cur.hasOwnProperty(type)){
        if(cur[type].indexOf(prev['ws_district']) == -1){
          cur[type].push(prev['ws_district'])
        }
      }else{
        cur[type] = [prev['ws_district']]
      }
      return cur
    },{})
console.log(result)
console.log(result['Speed Boat'])
```

Refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fu91dt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: How to store this reponse into array ? ex. into parent child

Comment: Do you refer the stack blitz link. can you elabrate what are you asking

Comment: this link is not accessable in my machine

Comment: I have used this code before but in this code child are not filtering var  result = _.values((this.information.reduce((r,o) => {
            r[o.ws_type] = r[o.ws_type] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_type: o.ws_type, children: []};
            //r[o.ws_district] = r[o.ws_district] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_district: o.ws_district, children: []};
            r[o.ws_type].children.push( r[o.ws_district] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_district: o.ws_district});
            return r;
          },{})));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168119/discussion-between-harshal-deshmukh-and-abinesh-joyel).

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter method and i updated my answer with
Referl link : https://jsfiddle.net/rv6d1byr/

```
let uniquedata = {}
let fruits = [
    {
        "ws_type": "Speed Boat",
        "ws_district": "Thane"
    },
    {
      "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
       "ws_district": "Thane"
    },
    {
        "ws_type": "Bumper ride",
      "ws_district": "Thane"
    }

]
let filtered = fruits.filter(obj => !uniquedata[obj.ws_type] && (uniquedata[obj.ws_type] = true));

 console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: can you tell with this code var  result = _.values((this.information.reduce((r,o) => {
            r[o.ws_type] = r[o.ws_type] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_type: o.ws_type, children: []};
            //r[o.ws_district] = r[o.ws_district] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_district: o.ws_district, children: []};
            r[o.ws_type].children.push( r[o.ws_district] ||  r[o.ws_district] ||{ws_district: o.ws_district});
            return r;
          },{}))); where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Sir i need output like this Required Result:

**- Speed Boat **

Raigad
Ratnagiri
Sindhudurg
Thane

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168088/discussion-between-harshal-deshmukh-and-manoj-bhardwaj).